# Aligning and arranging charts in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, gtable

I have two plots in ggplot with similar ranges on the axis that I would like to align.

Using:

```
library(grid)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(g1), ggplotGrob(g2), size = "last"))
```

where `size='last'` ensures the grids are aligned for x, I get a layout such as this:

[image]

The top chart has an excessive vertical range for the simple row I want to depict.

I would like to have an image more in keeping with the following:

[image]

Or alternatively, with the g1 chart aligned below the axis of the g2 chart. (For generality, let's say I want to be able to choose either, or even overlay g1 on top of g2.

(My original model was a single chart with the g1 component simply set as a layer in the g2 chart with y=0; however, the chart is too cluttered to read with that layout, so I thought I should move the original y=0 elements into a separate panel (i.e. g1).

**Minimal Example:**

```
size=50
df1=data.frame(x=seq(1,size),y=sample(-100:100,size,rep=TRUE))
df2=data.frame(x=seq(1,size),r=replicate(size,paste(sample(c(letters, LETTERS),3),collapse='')))
g1=ggplot(df1)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
g2=ggplot(df2)+geom_text(aes(x=x,y=0,label=r),angle=45,size=2)
library(grid) 
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(rbind(ggplotGrob(g1), ggplotGrob(g2), size = "last"))
```

I want the label strip (g2) to be positioned neatly with respect to the scatterplot. The g2 strip was part of the original chart as a `geom_text()` element at `y=0` but the chart was too cluttered around there with the labels placed there too.

Comment: use the `height` argument and specify as a fraction of the overall size. `grid.arrange(plot1, plot2, height = c(1/5.4/5) )` for example

Comment: But that loses the alignment from the example in the question? Also, `grid.arrange()` needs `library(gridExtra)`, and also (for this example) `nrows=2`?

Answer (score 4):

you simply need to edit the heights of the gtable,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
g1 <- g2 <- ggplotGrob(qplot(1,1))

g <- rbind(g1,g2,size="last")
id <- g$layout$t[g$layout$name == "panel"]
g$heights[id] <- lapply(c(1,4), "unit", "null")
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

Edit: with the more specific instructions, I'd suggest a different strategy: add the first panel only to the gtable of the second plot,

```
p1 <- ggplot(df1)+geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y))
p2 <- ggplot(df2)+geom_text(aes(x=x,y=0,label=r),angle=45,size=2)
snug <- theme_bw() + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.5,0.5,0,0),"line"))

library(gtable)
g1=gtable_filter(ggplotGrob(p1 + snug), pattern = "panel", trim = TRUE, fixed=TRUE)
g2=ggplotGrob(p2 + snug)

g <- g2
g <- gtable_add_rows(g, unit(0.2, "null"), 0)
g <- gtable_add_grob(g, g1, 1, 4)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(g)
```

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to give the effect I want. I think there are three issues I'm trying to addressl: 1) the large amounts of whitespace top and bottom in the g1 plot; 2) the ability to control the x-alignment and width of the two plots so they're the same; 3) the vertical relationship between the two plots. For the latter, eg how would I nudge one plot up or down while keeping the size of each plot the same?

Comment: had you provided a minimal reproducible example in your question, the answer could have been more exact to your specifications.

Comment: Apologies about that; example added.